# Pandas to_parquet fails with gzip

Tags: python, pandas, gzip, parquet

I have a question regarding pandas  `pd.to_parquet` function with the `compression = 'gzip'` option. Files created with this option are not recognized by  gzip utility.
I'm running AWSs ec2 instance with  Deep Learning Base AMI (Ubuntu 18.04) Version 53
python 3.6.9, pandas 1.1.5.

A file saved with

```py
df.to_parquet(path,  engine='pyarrow', compression='gzip')
```

has the size 6159 bytes.

`gzip -dv` throws an error " not in gzip format"

If I used gzip on the file saved without compression, i.e. first run

```py
df.to_parquet(path,  engine='pyarrow', compression=None)
```

and then gzip the .parquet file, the resulting .parquet.gz file has the size of 1511 bytes, and, needless to say, `gzip -dv` works just fine and restores the file.

I tried to google it, but came up with nothing.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide the first thirty or so bytes of the 6159-byte file in your question in hexadecimal or base64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pandas parquet to GZip does not GZip the parquet, but makes an internally GZipped parquet, the header of the file has the Parquet magic bytes (not the GZ ones!).

If you want to GZip you will have to use [GZip python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) after creating the Parquet. If the file is not too big, create the parquet on a BytesIO object, as it will be much faster.
Also, compression level time vs size is logarithmic, usually 9 is very slow and offers little advantage over 7.

**Note** that if I recall good, similarly pandas cannot load an externally GZ'd parquet, as it does not recognize the magic bytes. You should unGZip them also, possible with the same library.